# Missing "Include all" option in Timeshift backup?

Tags: backup

For some reason Timeshift doesn't allow me to backup my $HOME files and directory. The Include all option is missing in the Users Home Directories window, any idea what could be the cause ?

My home directory is encrypted.
[image: Screenshot of the Users Home Directories window]

Comment: What is your operating system and its version?

Comment: Hi, operating system is Ubuntu 18.04